# iReport with Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, ireport

I just installed iReport(Product Version: iReport Professional 3.7.1.1) and try to create exiting crystal report file using iReport to see it makes my life easier.

First bump that I faced was Oracle stored procedure. I found below post and tried to apply it.

> 1) Set the Query language in the Report Query to plsql
>
> 2) Use the following syntax for the call "{call MyPackage.MyStoredProc($P{Cursor},$P    {InputParam})}"
>
> 3) Define the Cursor param as java.sql.ResultSet
>
> 4) Type in the Fields of the result set by hand. I could not get the Automatically Retrieve Fields to work.
>
> I am using iReport 3.7.1 on Windows XP which is bundled with the jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar that contains the necessary PlSqlQueryExecuter classes.

I have conformed PlSqlQueryExecuter class exits in my classpath, the error message I got is

> The parameter 'Cursor' is not defined

Here is my question.
1. Does anyone know how to define Ref Curssor in the iReport?
2. How do I type in the fields of the result set by hand??

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set your Cusor out parameter datatype as java.sql.ResultSet you can do this by clicking the Add New Parameter and just type the data type as said above and click ok...Also make sure you uncheck the "Prompt for Parameter" in the Cursor's property in the report designer...

You can follow the article in the below link... this article gives a step by step instruction on how to create stored Procedures and call the stored procedure in your JasperReport / iReport... hope this helps

http://meezageekyside.blogspot.com/#!/2012/04/jasper-reports-ireport-45-using-oracle.html

keep us posted on your findings as well....